# Unwanted motor influence (RC snubber?)

Tags: ac, relay, emc, snubber

Trying to make motors control, but have very significant influence of the motors between each other.
When first motor is stopped (by built in limiter) second one (stopped) start turning cca 1/4 of turn (ignoring built in limiters and can create lot of damage).
The relays wiring and MCU commands are correct, tested many times, with one motor everything is perfect.

My **assumption** is that there is problem with the motors creating strong feedback voltage. I have read a lot about RC snubbers, but have seen at least 10 ways of calculation, leading to different results and do not know which one is correct. I here someone who can help with designing such a circuit? Will the circuit help at all?

Please have look at my schematics below. (only 220V part displayed)
[image]
Relays (even the MCU ones) always have 220V coil and also contacts. MCU switches them via own relays not displayed in schematics. Blue marked ones are common, because if not having the correct signals can result in physical damage so I do not want to rely on MCU and SW.

Motors have cca 0.55A when operating but depends on which wire you drive (I see variations on multimeter, but have no osciloscope). Motors are controlled by switching live to one or multiple inputs and have own position switches build in that are part of hw layout, have no documentation and can not be accessed (in schematics not displayed they are inside the M1, M2 circles). Relays have contact capacity of 10A so it should be fine.

**The red markings ?1(coil), ?2(contacts), ?3(motor) represent positions where maybe RC snubber is needed, but have no idea where and how to design them.** Should they be capacitor + resistor or TVS... Varistor I do not want as they degrade over time. Relays change position cca once in 5 min, but I need it to be robust, do not want to hear about it for next 10 years :-)

Summary what I have until now:

- Cap+Resistor fails to short not such a good idea, and capacitors are short lived elements
- TVS seems better, but I can not find anything with performance, max is 1-2 watts :-(
- Calculation for RC: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/162137/215231, [How to calculate Snubber for different load value](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/87701/how-to-calculate-snubber-for-different-load-value)
- TVS selection found limited information on power sizing and do not know if Stand-Off Voltage is in RMS or peak?? http://www.protekdevices.com/xyz/documents/kb/tech/ta1020.pdf usually they calculate us for peak, but because the other motor can turn 1/4 of turn it is much longer peak.

I have build few ideas with DC, raspberry pi, NRF, Arduino and know a little about DC, but absolutelly nothing about AC.

I tested everything with MCu and also manually connecting. Driving circuit is correct, error is in engines they must send some bad currents back.

The L in schematics is live, N is neutral and PE is 'second' neutral. the 2 neutrals are either way connected so no big difference.

Comment: I’d suggest varistors across the relay coils and across the  contacts. Sure varistors degrade but I’ve had ones out in the field for over 15 years. For RC snubber capacitors, use X2 rated mains caps. They are designed to fail open circuit. They too degrade over time.

Comment: For the degradation reasons my favorite would be diode TVS. Should it be cap I'm aware of the X2, but I'm surprised that they fail open, I have seen that they fail short and all failed capacitors I have seen have failed short. Can you post some link so I can learn more about this?

Comment: Out of the three choices, TVS diode is most likely to fail short. MOVs and capacitors tend to be much more robust. Maybe you want a Y class capacitor?  Allen Bradley/Rockwell Automation and others have app notes on various suppression techniques  with relays and contactors switching motor loads.

Comment: I can't see a single flyback diode anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Based on below links I decided to use C=0.39 uF and R=420 OHM.

Can maybe someone give me hint what is difference between these 2 caps? [B32033A4394M000](https://uk.farnell.com/epcos/b32033a4394m000/suppression-cap-0-39uf-class-y2/dp/2943779) Y2, 350V and [MKP385E4392BJPM2T0](https://uk.farnell.com/vishay/mkp385e4392bjpm2t0/cap-0-39uf-2-5kv-film-radial/dp/3215968) 800V, the first one has Y2 rating, but all parameters are significantly worse than second one. Everybody recommends Y2, but what is the reasoning behind when much better versions exists (from my amateur view)?

As resistor I have chosen this one [ROX9J430R](https://uk.farnell.com/neohm-te-connectivity/rox9j430r/res-430r-9w-axial-metal-oxide/dp/3230194) 9W,750V.

Any opinions about my choice?

Links used for calculation:
https://sciencing.com/design-rc-snubber-12030206.html
https://www.edaboard.com/threads/calculation-the-power-of-resistor-in-a-snubber.293843/
https://www.mathforengineers.com/AC-circuits-calculators/current-and-voltages-calculator-for-series%20RLC-circuits.html
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/help-a-newbie-pls-rc-snubber-values-for-240v-ac/694211/5

Comment: This is looks like an addendum to your question. If so, please edit your question post (click the "Edit" link at the lower left of the question) instead of posting an "answer".